# How to use dispatchEvent function from JavaScript without event data to Angular 12 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I need to use document.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', 'The string that I try to send when fire event from code')) but an sintaxis error was trigged with this code because the second argument of CustomEvent must be an object, can't be an simple string, this is the first problem, I must send the event without data only with simple string and receive it without any another data in angular callback function, any thing about it?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Angular's @Output if you only want to pass data to the parent components.

```
@Output() public myCustomEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

....
this.myCustomEvent.emit('The string that I try to send when fire event from code')
```

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs